# How to arrange table border in iTextSharp

Tags: asp.net, itext

I am trying to make a trial balance report.I want the format like below attached format.how can I make a table like this
[image]

I tried,

```
table.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.RIGHT_BORDER | Rectangle.RIGHT_BORDER;
```

but the code gives only vertical lines.how can I make table like above attached format?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't understand the meaning of the [bitwise `|` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx.aspx), because this doesn't make sense:

```
table.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.RIGHT_BORDER | Rectangle.RIGHT_BORDER;
```

The line above is the equivalent of:

```
table.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.RIGHT_BORDER;
```

Also: you shouldn't expect different cells to have a different border if you use `table.DefaultCell.Border`. You are asking iTextSharp to draw all implicitly created cells in such a way that they only have a border to the right. Why are you surprised when iTextSharp obeys that command?

You need to create each `PdfPCell` explicitly and define a border for each one of them:

```
PdfPCell left_cell = new PdfPCell();
left_cell.Border = Rectangle.RIGHT_BORDER | Rectangle.TOP_BORDER | Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER;
// add stuff to left_cell
table.AddCell(left_cell);
PdfPCell middle_cell = new PdfPCell();
middle_cell.Border = Rectangle.TOP_BORDER | Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER;
// add stuff to middle_cell
table.AddCell(middle_cell);
PdfPCell right_cell = new PdfPCell();
right_cell.Border = Rectangle.LEFT_BORDER | Rectangle.TOP_BORDER | Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER;
// add stuff to right_cell
table.AddCell(right_cell);
```

In your code, you could apply different borders to `DefaultCell` before each `AddCell()` invocation, but that doesn't really make much sense. It's better to create a custom `getCell()` method that creates `PdfPCell` instances exactly the way you prefer.

Comment: Yes, Actually I were not aware about | operator.Let me try as you said

Comment: I've added a link to the [bitwise `|` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx.aspx), which is a very common operator in programming languages. The fact that you don't know it tells me that you've never studied computer sciences.

Comment: Which version will support the above code.For me it shows error like "iTextSharp.text.Rectangle does not contain a definition for 'RIGHT'"

Comment: I don't really know about iTextSharp, but the constants I refer to have always been present in the `Rectangle` class: http://developers.itextpdf.com/reference/com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle Maybe the names in iTextSharp are different, maybe not.

Comment: iTextSharp `Rectangle.RIGHT_BORDER` is the iText equivalent of `Rectangle.RIGHT`. i.e. both are `int` with value of `8`.

Comment: @kuujinbo OK, thanks, I'll update my answer. Strange that there's a difference between iText and iTextSharp...

Comment: @BrunoLowagie - I agree it's strange there's a difference. It's been so long since I converted the book examples from Java to C# I forgot too, and actually went looking into the 4.1.6 iTextSharp branch for `Rectangle.RIGHT`.